# Bluetooth headset A2dp on iPad not working

Tags: ios, bluetooth

This seems like a basic tech support question, but google is failing me....

I just paired a bluetooth headset (single ear) with my iPad. This headset is known for having a very good a2dp profile built in and is advertised to allow one to stream music from one's smartphone in addition to taking calls.

So far the only app that has given me audio in the headset is Talkatone (a VoIP app). iTunes U, iTunes, google chrome, safari, and YouTube output audio through the iPad's speakers.

How do I configure any of these apps to use my headset for audio?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.  I did consult the headset manual, which had one sentence about A2DP, which just said essentially "it only works on phones that support it".

In fact, all I had to do to move from where I was to the headset working as I expected was to force-close and reopen each iPad app that I wanted to hear through the headset.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like only the phone profile was paired with the iPad. You probably need to pair the A2DP profile separately. Refer to the manual of the bluetooth headset, especially where it talks about pairing it to an iPod or any other music playing device.

For example, my Prius has both the phone profile and the audio profile. I must go through 2 separate pairings to get both of them to work. It is not enough to go through a single pairing of the phone capabilities and start having it play audio through my Music app. I am guessing something similar is happening with your bluetooth headset.

Another thing you can try is seeing where the audio currently goes when you use FaceTime. I would presume that it does work with the bluetooth headset because it is the closest thing to a phone call on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my plantronics.  I removed the BT from my IPad, then reconnected.  It worked fine then.